# SQL query: find each item that costs more than the average and how much more

Tags: sql

I'm doing some revision for a databases exam and one of the questions is as follows:

Given the table `Items` (columns: `itemid`, `description`, `unitcost`), formulate a query to find each item that costs more than the average and how much more than the average it costs.

My answer so far is

```
SELECT itemid, 
       description, 
       unitcost - AVG(unitcost) 
FROM Items 
WHERE unitcost > (SELECT AVG(unitcost) FROM Items)
```

- Would this work? From what I understand, expressions are allowed in the list of selected columns but I'm not sure if that extends to the use of functions like `AVG()`.
- Is there a cleaner, clearer way to express the same thing? Preferably using only ISO SQL constructs because my course is rather theoretical and not connected to any specific dialect.

Thanks friends :)

Comment: No, it would not work because you are missing a `group by`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `GROUP BY` what and why?

Comment: What happened when you ran it on a standard compliant DBMS? (hint: MySQL is not compliant)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't even have access to a proper computer right now, let alone a database (would've used MySQL in my ignorance if I did though :P)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: not the way it is used in the query. Because the select list contains an aggregate as well as non-aggregated columns, a `group by` is required (at least for any DBMS which wants to return deterministic results) - although grouping will not return the desired result.

Comment: @Elliot: you can test this online. Here is your query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/cdb33/2

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are correct of course.. my bad

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks once again for your advice. I learned about the `GROUP BY` requirement on aggregate/column combinations and discovered sqlfiddle -- success! I'll have to do some research on why that restriction exists though because it's not immediately clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One query that should work with almost any version of SQL (that accepts the explicit JOIN syntax) would be:

```
SELECT i.itemid, 
       i.description, 
       i.unitcost - a.avg_cost cost_diff
FROM (SELECT AVG(unitcost) avg_cost FROM Items) a
JOIN Items i
ON i.unitcost > a.avg_cost
```

Comment: This looks very close to the answer I would expect to see in the mark scheme -- i.e. using only the basic constructs taught on the course. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The original query can be turned into a valid (ANSI SQL) query with a slight change (using window functions):

```
select itemid, 
       description, 
       unitcost - avg(unitcost) over() as delta 
from items 
where unitcost > (select avg(unitcost) from items);
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/cdb33/1

Comment: Thanks for your help! :) I upvoted this but I ticked the answer that looks closest to what I would expect on the mark scheme for the paper (unfortunately window functions weren't taught on the course!)

Answer (score 1):

In most dialects of SQL, you can use window functions for this.  That is, you can have a `partition` clause for the `avg()` function:

```
SELECT itemid, 
       description, 
       unitcost - avgcost
FROM (select i.*, avg(unitcost) over () as avgcost
      from Items i
     ) i
WHERE unitcost > avgcost
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work but I don't understand why you are trying to do subtraction?

```
SELECT id, 
       title, 
       sort_price,
sort_price - (SELECT AVG(sort_price) as avg FROM item)
FROM item
WHERE sort_price> (SELECT AVG(sort_price) as items FROM item)
```

Comment: That wouldn't give me the difference though :(

Comment: @ergec the OP also asked "**and how much more than the average it costs***"

Answer (score 0):

The `WITH` clausa is ANSI SQL, so you can write something like:

```
WITH ap AS
 ( SELECT AVG(unitcost) avguc FROM Items )
SELECT i.itemid
     , i.description
     , (unitcost - a.avguc) avg_uc_diff 
FROM Items
   , ap a 
WHERE unitcost > a.avguc
```